# как написать тест для авторизованного пользователя?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

помогите пожалуйста советом.

я написал тест для экшена edit:

```
  setup do
    @user = users(:one)  
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get :edit, id: @user
    assert_response :success
    assert_template :edit
    assert_template layout: "layouts/application"           
  end
```

users.yml:
one:

```
  name: 'onfge'
  email: 'MyStrdfing@ad.ad'
  password_digest: '$2a$10$XS2HLwMZxg/7yRKAWd9AJ.afCMra0wGWK4b.FhkY/qo3Lmo/tKEiO'
  remember_token: 'dc3461e13c8d316dad22332a503e06edafa0b9cb'
  phone: '43535345'
  skype: 'gggggg'
  gender: one
  info: 'MyString'
  admin: true
  avatar_file_name: nil
  avatar_content_type: nil
  avatar_file_size: nil
```

проблема в том, что к странице /users/2/edit доступ есть только у пользователя, прошедшего аутентификацию. сейчас происходит перенаправление на страницу аутентификации.

скажите пожалуйста как реализовать успешную аутентификацию в тесте?

Answer (score 1):

Я пишу тесты с использованием RSpec и FactoryGirl. В RSpec данная задача решается созданием стаба(stub, заглушка) для метода `current_user` тестируемого контроллера.

Пример:

```
controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(FactoryGirl.build :user, :admin)
```

Comment: спасибо. но для меня это пока единственный плюс от rspec